# Jquery - Get element by id constructing the id in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a trouble using an element with jquery. I am constructing the name in a var such as:

```
var myId = "#" + myGotId;

$(myId).attr("title", "changed");
```

$(myId) is returning empty. I would want to get my element by id but constructing my Id dynamically joining strings.

*edit by @Pointy* — additional code supplied in a comment by the OP:

```
var form = $('form#formDefaultValue');
$(':submit', form).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(data, status, XMLHttpRequest) {
    if (status == 'success') {
      $("#msgInformation").html("Your changes have been successfully saved.");
      jQuery("#spanDefaultValue").attr("class", "db");
      var g = indexNodeSelected;
      g = g.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\");
      $('#'+ g).find("span").attr("class", "");
   }
```

Comment: It should. Check the value of myId is what you expect.

Comment: What is the value of `myGotId`? Are you sure you don't mean `"#" + "myGotId"`? If an element with that ID doesn't exist, then neither dynamically joining strings, nor something else will help you.

Comment: David is correct, check the value for `myGotId` to ensure it is setting `myId` to the appropriate value. Here is a working example with your code. http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/kjpNN/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know exactly what is happening because you have not posted much code, but make sure that your Javascript code is running *after* the element with your target "id" value has been included in the DOM. If you have this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var myId = '#' + myGotId;
      $(myId).whatever();
```

then that won't work because the actual page will not have been seen when your code runs.

Instead, try this:

```
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var myId = '#' + myGotId;
      // ...
    });
```

It is also important to make sure that your "myGotId" string is exactly the value you expect (that is, the value coded into the "id" attribute of your target element).

*edit* If you think that you're correctly constructing the "id", then you could try this as an alternative:

```
$(document.getElementById(myGotId)).whatever()
```

In other words, you can "wrap" a plain DOM element up in a jQuery object by just passing to the `$()` function. If that works, then the problem could be that your "id" value is somehow confusing the selector engine. Does the "id" value contain "." by any chance?

Comment: var form = $('form#formDefaultValue');
$(':submit', form).click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(),
        function(data, status, XMLHttpRequest) {
            if (status == 'success') {
                $("#msgInformation").html("Your changes have been successfully saved.");
                jQuery("#spanDefaultValue").attr("class", "db");
                var g = indexNodeSelected;
                g = g.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\");
              $('#'+ g)).find("span").attr("class", "");
            }

Comment: when I inspect the hardcoded value in firebug it gets my element, when I construct the element with $ ('#' + g)  in inspector and script it is empty.

Comment: What is "indexNodeSelected" supposed to be?  Where is that defined?  Is it supposed to be a string?

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you haven't tried it before: use alert() function here and there to see when you code is called and what is the value of myId before you pass it to jQuery selector. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well I used an alert to show my final constructed Id and it is correct. I don't know why it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Why are you doing that replacement with all the backslashes?  What is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: If I use the document.getElementById I can get the element, but how can I use the returned value with jquery?
I would want to do something like: 
var myspanElement = document.getElementById("MyId").find("span").attr("title", "changed")

Answer (score 4):

The reason your jQuery isn't working as expected is because it is executing before the DOM is fully loaded into the browser.

Put your jQuery code in a document ready function and it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // code that will run once the entire DOM is loaded into the browser
});
```

Example webpage => http://mikegrace.s3.amazonaws.com/forums/stack-overflow/example-get-element-by-constructed-string.html

Example Firebug console output

[image: Example Firebug console output]

What happened here?

1. as soon as the script loaded it started executing
2. console.log output 'Dom may not be ready yet'
3. jQuery selector returned nothing
4. DOM fully loaded into browser starting the document ready function
5. jQuery selector returned expected results

Why?

Scripts can load before a browser has a chance to parse the HTML on a page. Before a browser can fully parse the DOM and build it's DOM tree it won't be able to tell you if an element exists or not. This is why running the jQuery selector before the document is ready will often result in unexpected results.

Example script

```
//run possibly before DOM is loaded into browser
var selector = "#crazy-image";
console.log("DOM may not be ready yet");
console.log($(selector));
$(document).ready(function () {
  // code that will run once the entire DOM is loaded into the browser
  console.log("DOM ready");
  console.log($(selector));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you need the extra variable?  Try without it, like this:

```
$("#" + myGotId).attr("title", "changed");
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe the special characters in the name are affecting: 
var g =  indexNodeSelected;
g = g.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\");
 $("#" + g ).attr("title", "changed");            
This is the id of my element, and with four "\\\\" it works:
//$("#WindowsAdapter-8CD2DEB979A0188\\\\TextBox-8CD2DEB9E5CECC4").attr("title", "changed");

Comment: it doenst work when I construct the id dinamically in my variables

Comment: Well, sorry, I found the problem:
I was using 4 backslashes g = g.replace("\\", "\\\\\\\\");
I changed my replace for  g = g.replace("\\", "\\\\");
and now it works...!

Answer (score 0):

As this example show, your code should be working :
Make sure you execute the script after the element you want to get has been created.
Make sure the id is correct.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">Hello</div>

<script>
var myGotId = 'mydiv';
var myId = "#" + myGotId;
$(myId).attr("title", "changed");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I use inspector of firebug there is the element created. I think maybe the special characters in id name are affecting