# How to dynamic select element with JQuery by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to dynamic select element with JQuery, I get in code id of element. How to do that ?
I've tried:

```
var sel='\'#'+id+'\'';
var elem+$(sel);
```

but it doesn't work ( id is string id of element).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - Get element by id constructing the id in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325278/jquery-get-element-by-id-constructing-the-id-in-string)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You would use code such as

```
var ID = 'whatEver';
$('#' + ID).action();
```

You would then be able to use that to select whatever element you are after.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need the extra quotes. Just:

```
var elem = $("#"+id);
```

Answer (score 0):

A live example:: to find text area with attribute data-comment-id with any value

```
var value = "anyValue";
$('textarea[data-comment-id='+value+']')
```